# Use custom fonts with androidx

Tags: android, fonts, androidx

I'm currently trying to add a custom font family to my Android project which is using Androidx instead of the old support library.

But I can't seem to find a way to support font families in older SDK versions (23+) with the AndroidX libraries and everything I find online is mentioning the old support library.

My current font family file looks like this:

```
<font-family
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="500"
        app:font="@font/raleway_medium"/>

    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="700"
        app:font="@font/raleway_bold" />

    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="600"
        app:font="@font/raleway_semibold" />

</font-family>
```

Is there a way to make this work on older SDK versions with the androidx libraries?

Comment: Yes, I have this problem too.  My app was working beautifully with a large group of custom fonts.  Then we upgraded from v7 to androidX, and poof: no more custom fonts (but only on emulators and devices--the custom fonts still displayed perfectly in the preview panes, sigh)!  Thank you google!

Comment: I am facing similar issue, any solution for this?

Comment: Any luck @ScottBiggs, can you help how to fix this

Comment: @SaadBilal  It's weird--sometimes I can get it to work, sometimes I can't.  It seems dependent on the device, the version of Android, and which way the wind blows.  Obviously I don't have a good idea of what is actually happening.  Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your fonts with the `app` and with the `android` attributes. So it will work for "all" sdk versions.

```
<font
    android:font="@font/myfont"
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    app:font="@font/myfont"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="400" />
```

When you declared your font you can apply it in xml via:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/customfont</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/customfont</item>
...
```

or programmatically via:

```
val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.customfont)
textView.typeface = typeface
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but even with this change I can't get it to work on devices prior to Android 8. Do you know which androidx library I need to make it work on older versions? All I see online is `com.android.support:support-v4` but this won't do with androidx.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit. Please check again. If it does not work, can you show some code etc? Cheers

Comment: Yeah, the OP is asking what AndroidX package to use to get the SupportV4 working - otherwise the code is failing Lint

Comment: I too am getting compile errors.  What library do I need to include in the gradle files for this to work?

Comment: Any luck? I am stuck on this too

Comment: I'm stuck too. This is so lame.

Answer (score 1):

In your XML file, you should replace `TextView` with `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView`.